# Custom source handler for Jquery plugin Levitip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an application using Jquery and the levitip plugin. I need to write a new source handler in jquery.levitip.js this kind of call to levitip to be possible:

```
$("Tag").leviTip({sourceType: 'pertsonalizatua', source: '#Mached_Tag_atribute' , addClass: ''});
```

I want the levitip to show the element with the same id as `$(this).attr(Mached_Tag_atribute)`

I dont know how the handler would look. I am a newbie in jquery. Thank you.

The handler I wrote so far is this:

```
$.LeviTip.addSourceHandler({
        type: 'pertsonalizatua',
        prepare: function(levitip)
        {
            if ( levitip.settings.hideSourceElement )
            {
                $(levitip.settings.source).hide();
            }
        },
        get: function(levitip)
        {
            var $e = [];
            if ( levitip.settings.source )
            {
                $e = $(levitip.target).attr(levitip.settings.source);
                if ( $e.length )
                    $e = $e.clone(true).show();
            }
            return $e;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure this selector is legal `$("Tag")`, what were you trying to select with this line?

Comment: Hello, I just put "Tag" meaning that was the tag type the levitip was matching. What I am trying to select is a div element that has the same id as the mached tags Mached_Tag_atribute attributes value.Any idea @ajax333221 ?

Comment: @H :( nope, not ideas. But I think you should link to the levitip.js thing

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/levitip/. Someone, any idea?